# Seeking three Schengen (tourist) entries with travel to US for 5 weeks and Croatia for 3 days in between

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I am travelling from India with the following itinerary:

1. India -> Germany (April 1, 2018- April 21, 2018) = 21 days
2. Germany -> USA (April 21, 2018- June 30, 2018) = 39 days [not Schengen - I already have a 10 year US visa]
3. USA -> Italy (July 1, 2018- July 15, 2018) = 15 days
4. Italy -> Croatia (July 15, 2018- July 17, 2018) = 3 days [not Schengen - but requires a multiple-entry Schengen visa]
5. Croatia -> Germany (July 18, 2018 - July 20, 2018) = 3 days
6. Germany -> India (July 20, 2018)

I can see I will need a multiple-entry Schengen visa valid for at least 6 months or so. But I'm confused what the number of days permitted for my "Duration of Stay" in Schengen will be. i.e. What should I seek in duration of stay? Will they grant 90 days or an exact number of days?

Comment: They may grant 90 days, but more likely just the exact number of days, possibly with a few days extra for safety's sake.  In addition, you obviously don't need a six-month visa; they might just as well give you a four-month visa.  But why does it matter?  If your visa application is successful, you will get a visa allowing you to follow your proposed itinerary.  (Also, in contrast to your title, you are proposing three entries into the Schengen area, not two.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, @phoog - Yes I understand a 4 month validity is fair too. My worry is more around boxing in exact number of days. You reckon submitting the above itinerary will likely result in them granting me stay of 39 days? Isn't there any buffer for flexibility? What shouldI fill in Duration sought? I do apologize for the mistake in the title - indeed I should've entered 3 and not 2 (I edited it).

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know what the German authorities' practice is with regard to giving extra days for flexibility.  There are questions on this site indicating that some visas are granted with and others without such a buffer (the only one I remember without a buffer, though, was granted by Italy).  Since the form asks for the "duration of intended stay," however, it seems pretty clear that you should enter 39 there.

Comment: Unless you have a history of traveling to Schengen, I highly doubt you'll be successful with an application with that itinerary with an Indian passport.

Comment: Err - what does that mean exactly? What do you reckon are the grounds for disapproving such an application?

Comment: @greatone why?  What does the itinerary have to do with it?